# Sent date parameter to another Activity but value is zero // android studio

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

i trying to create Simple calendar on android , which i have problem when i try to sent parameter (date, month, year) from MainActivity to another Acvitity that parameter is 0

MainActivity.java

`public void onClick(View view) {
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
                localBundle.putInt("Date", i2);
                localBundle.putInt("Month", i1);
                localBundle.putInt("Year", i);
            }
        });
        if(view == buttonGetDate1) {
            Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
            localIntent.putExtras(localBundle);
            startActivity(localIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }`

TestAcvitity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    datedisplay1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_display1);
    datedisplay1.setText("Date: ");

    buttonBack1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
    buttonBack1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
    int day = intent.getInt("date");
    int month = intent.getInt("month");
    int year = intent.getInt("year");
    Log.d(TAG, "THIRD LOG : "  + day  + " / " + month + " / " + year);
    datedisplay1.setText("Date: " + day  + " / " + month + " / " + year);
}
```

[But it's show 0/0/0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqm9C.jpg)

how i can fix it ?
ps. sorry for my bad English skill.

EDIT : after i try debug log 
EDIT2: updated TestActivity

[in this pic, intent have value are Date = 30 Year = 2017 Month = 4 but it's show null on application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yomd7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data goes empty because you reinitializing bundle on  click again, i have done some change in your code just give a try

```
{
 //inside your activity on create scope  
 int dateData=0;
 int monthData=0; 
 int yearData=0;  
 calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            dateData= i2;
            monthData= i1;
            yearData= i;


//Log here whether u getting date here?
        }
    });


public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view == buttonGetDate1) {

       Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
       localBundle.putInt("Date", dateData);
       localBundle.putInt("Month", monthData);
       localBundle.putInt("Year", yearData); 


        Intent localIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
        localIntent.putExtras(localBundle);
        startActivity(localIntent);
        finish();

    }
  }
}//Activity scope ends
```

TestAcvitity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

datedisplay1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_display1);
datedisplay1.setText("Date: ");

buttonBack1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
buttonBack1.setOnClickListener(this);
Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
int day = intent.getInt("Date");
int month = intent.getInt("Month");
int year = intent.getInt("Year");
Log.d(TAG, "THIRD LOG : "  + day  + " / " + month + " / " + year);
datedisplay1.setText("Date: " + day  + " / " + month + " / " + year);
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for advice but at Android Monitor it's show Log.d("LOG","YOUR BUNDLE IS NULL"); and i can't press button too.

Comment: ok so your bundle is empty? did u log on the date selection also.

Comment: ok, at log on date selection they have value :  
bundle value Date: 23
bundle value Month: 4
bundle value Year: 2017

Comment: ok still after selecting date you getting  Log.d("LOG","YOUR BUNDLE IS NULL");  on button click ???

Comment: i dont know how you code works but i have made a new edit on the answer, please check

Comment: after on button click 
if(view == buttonGetDate1) Log.d("LOG","YOUR BUNDLE IS NULL1");
it's show LOG","YOUR BUNDLE IS NULL1 that it mean buddle is empty after onclick ?

Comment: ok, value were sent but it's show 0/0/0 . then i will updated code in TestActivity on post.

Comment: check the new edit and check testactivty    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
int day = intent.getInt("Date");
int month = intent.getInt("Month");
int year = intent.getInt("Year");
Log.d(TAG, "THIRD LOG : "  + day  + " / " + month + " / " + year);

Comment: finally it was solve. because i wring typing from Uppercase to Lowercase that it make null because it unknown day, month, year Right?

Comment: Thank you for helping me very much. Ramz :)